# Due to different browser,my url was encode into '%3d' and tomcat can't handle it

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I got a problem with my tomcat server. I got  links  look something like this:

```
/getorder?userId%253Dmaq5uCnE  or /getorder?userId%3Dmaq5uCnE
```

however it should be like:

```
/getorder?userId=maq5uCnE
```

I check the nginx access.log  and find that, all the wrong links has a userAgent info like "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"  or Windows Nt 5.1 ;

How can I fix it? Thank you for your help;

Comment: `%3D` is the URL Encoding version of `=`. `%25` is thee URL Encoding for `%`

So, somewhere, in the first example, the `=` is getting double URL Encoded.

Comment: yeah,I know it's encoded but i can't use this link ,how can i covert it into the way it should be

Comment: I agree with @Alan this sounds more like an issue with double-encoding the '=' . Can you please share your code that is reading/writing these URLs?